# how to pass own dictionary to sub-template

Tags: python, templates, template-engine, bottle

using `bottlepy` with the `simple template engine` i wonder how i could pass the entire dictionary that was *passed* to the template on to it's sub-templates.

e.g. in my `main.py` i have:

```
@bottle.route('/')
@bottle.view('main')
def index():
    """main page"""
    return {"name": "main", "foo": 12, "flag": True}
```

and i want to pass on **all** the values in the dictionary from my `main.tpl` to a `sub.tpl`

```
$ cat sub.tpl
<h1>Hello, {{name}}</h1>

$ cat main.tpl
% include('subtemplate', name=name, foo=foo, flag=flag)
```

enumerating each key (as in the above example), is of course not very scalable nor flexible.

so: is there a way to pass on the entire environment?

something like

```
$ cat main.tpl
% include('subtemplate', *env)
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass: `include('subtemplate', index())`?

Comment: @JossieCalderon infinite recursion?

Comment: @LukasGraf I don't see how? Please? Educate? Me?

Comment: @JossieCalderon calling `index()` will render the `main` template again, from which `index()` will be called again, ... Unless bottle / STE does some magic to detect that loop and break it, I can't see how that wouldn't end in infinite recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought, off the top of me head. (I.e., untested.)

```
@bottle.route('/')
@bottle.view('main')
def index():
    """main page"""
    env = {"name": "main", "foo": 12, "flag": True}  # same vars as before
    env["env"] = env  # add a reference to the entire dict, for passing deeper into subtemplates
    return env
```

And then:

```
% include('subtemplate', env=env)
```

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Kwartz for suggesting the following improvement.

A cleaner method would be, simply:

```
% include('subtemplate', **env)
```

Have not tried it, but if `**locals()` works (h/t to @Lukas Graf for trying it and confirming), then it's reasonable to expect `**env` to work as well.

Comment: Or, better yet, `% include('subtemplate', **env)`

Comment: @Kwarrtz That would be nice, indeed.  Not sure off the top of my head whether param expansion works in a Bottle template.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried it with `% include('subtemplate', **locals())`, which seemed to work. But that will pass along the entire scope of `main`, which might have unintended side-effects, so I like your aproach with constructing your own `env` better.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update the answer to include that fact.